# WPF ComboBox clear

Tags: wpf

I have Two radio buttons.   If i check first radio button The below data will populate in the combobox. After that i will check another radio button, i want to clear the combo box values.

```xml
<RadioButton Height="29"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="143,193,0,0" Name="rdoEmployee" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61"
             FontSize="20"  Checked="rdoEmployee_Checked" GroupName="rdoEmployee/>

<RadioButton FontSize="20" Height="20" Margin="228,193,0,0" Name="rdoPA" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="49"  
             Checked="rdoPA_Checked" GroupName="rdoEmployee />

<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="142,235,0,240" 
          Name="cmbEmpType" Width="200" FontSize="16" />
```

```cs
EmployeeTypes _ET = new EmployeeTypes();
DataRowCollection drc = _ET.EmpTypeTable.Rows;
foreach (DataRow r in drc)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
    item.Tag = r["EmpTypeID"];
    item.Content = r["EmpTypeName"];

    cmbEmpType.Items.Add(item);

    if (cmbEmpType.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        cmbEmpType.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you asking for

```
cmbEmpType.Items.Clear();
```

This should empty your combo.

Answer (score 0):

Is it bound? If so, set the bound property to `null`. If not, set `SelectedItem` to `null`.

Comment: Not working Kent. I bind the combobox from db. When i check the radio buton check, i want to clear the combox box.

Comment: Please edit your original question and include XAML and relevant code. Can't help without sufficient info.